# Pushing using Git from a pc to another without using Github

Tags: git, git-extensions

Im brand new with Git. I need to know whether its possible to create a repository on my computer and push it to another one directly without using Github. I want to use a computer as a server to be pushed and pulled from. Im also using GitExtensions

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible there are many tutorials for setting up your git server. Probably the easiest way I've found is to use `ssh` with a `git` user on the server who houses all of the git repos. Unless you have a server already connected through the internet though it might be hard getting the same functionality up and running (you would have to be on the local subnet to push and pull). Take a look here: https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server. If you need to access your repo from anywhere (git is distributed so this is not necessary) you could always port forward your `ssh` on your router and use DDNS if you don't have a server (recommended to limit your `ssh` to use only key based authentication), but that gets more complicated.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've read the article in the link you sent but actually I dont have a server that's set on any of my computers, as i unsderstood i need to setup a server on one of them first then use SSH to allow developers to clone or push into the repository thats on the server computer, is tha right? Im a very beginner with using servers

Comment: @NadHelmy Technically you don't even need a "server" you just need a computer connected to the local network running `ssh`. I recommend a `git` user which has `authorized_keys` which would allow your developers to clone and push on the local subnet

Comment: I'm very sorry but whats authorized_keys?

Comment: @NadHelmy No need to be sorry. This is a website for asking questions. It's allows a computer to `ssh` using keys rather than having to manually enter your password every time. This works much better. Googling `ssh authorized_keys` should help

Comment: My computers are on the same internet network, are they considered connected to the local network running ssh as you said?

Comment: @NadHelmy All that matters is you can reach them. You can use ping or a network scanner to test. As for if they are running `ssh` I don't know. That is up to you

Comment: any idea how to make them run ssh?

Comment: @NadHelmy that depends on your OS. There are plenty of tutorials out there. Google a bunch and ask new questions if you get stuck.

Answer (score -1):

You can setup your own git repository server. If you're running a Linux-based operating system you can follow [this really good tutorial](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/824358-how-to-run-your-own-git-server) from Linux.com for example.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: You may explain tutorial's important points here. So even the link page changes we have some relevant information in your answer.